# How can fix collect2: Error: ld returned 1 exit status in Ubuntu

Tags: make

mkdir -p lib
gcc -o lib/libnlsartoolbox.so tools/sarerror.o tools/sarprintf.o tools/sarwaitbar.o tools/matrixtools.o tools/inv_func.o data/iorat.o data/iobin.o data/ioxima.o data/iosar.o data/ionetpbm.o data/sardata.o data/rgbdata.o data/fltdata.o data/sar2rgb.o algos/carfilter/sarboxcar.o algos/carfilter/sardiskcar.o algos/carfilter/sargausscar.o 
algos/carfilter/fltboxcar.o algos/nlsar/nlsar.o algos/nlsar/sarsimstats.o algos/nlsar/sarsim_glrwishart.o algos/nlsar/phi.o algos/noisegen/noisegen.o -shared  -lm -lpthread -lfftw3f -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -llapack -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
        tools/sarerror.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
        collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
        Makefile:90: recipe for target 'lib/libnlsartoolbox.so' failed
        make: *** [lib/libnlsartoolbox.so] Error 1

i want to install libnlsartoolbox.

> ./configure
>   make
>   sudo make install
>   The configuration is succeed but when am doing make am getting error saying that tools/sarerror.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It sounds like you are trying to link object files that were generated for a different OS architecture than your native one. Please [edit] you question to give us more context.

Comment: /sarerror.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized

Comment: collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status Makefile:90: recipe for target 'lib/libnlsartoolbox.so' failed make: *** [lib/libnlsartoolbox.so] Error 1

Comment: I meant "context" as in (1) what software you are trying to build (2) where you obtained it (3) what steps you took leading up to the error. If you are following an online installation guide please link it.

Comment: Can you help me to fix this

Comment: i want to install libnlsartoolbox but am getting an error when reading it.tools/sarerror.o: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'lib/libnlsartoolbox.so' failed
make: *** [lib/libnlsartoolbox.so] Error 1

Comment: All this information should be in the body of your question: please use the [edit] button to add it

Comment: Well I can't find any reference to `libnlsartoolbox` outside of this askubuntu question, so I can only assume it's some private software. My best  guess is that it came with pre-compiled `.o` files that are inappropriate for your OS/architecture, but are not being re-generated because (based on their timestamps relative to the source files) they are not out-of-date. You may need to run `make clean` or (if the `Makefile` does not define a `clean` target) move or delete the `.o` files so that new native ones get compiled.